# d3.js nested data update line plot in html table

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a dashboard with d3.  I am putting bullet plots and sparklines into a table.  I have been able to put the bullet plots in without any trouble, but I can't get the paths for the line plots.  My data is nested and the below appends an svg and path correctly, but the path is empty.  I have tried multiple update patterns and I do not see why I can't get any data for the path with the below.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.  Thanks.

```js
data = [{data:{data1:[{index:1, value:5},{index:2, value:9}]}}]
    
    
sparkScaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,10])
  .range([10,0])
sparkScaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,10])
  .range([0,15])
    
line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return sparkScaleX (d.index); })
  .y(function(d) { return sparkScaleY (d.value); });
    
rows = d3.select("tbody")
 .selectAll("tr")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("tr")
    
spark = rows.append('td')
 .append('svg')
 .attr("class", "spark-svg")
 .attr("width", 15)
 .attr("height", 10)
 .append('path')
    
spark
  .attr("class", "spark-path")
    
function update(data){
    
  sparkSvg = d3.selectAll(".spark-svg")
     .data(data)
    
  sparkPath = sparkSvg.selectAll('.spark-path')
     .data(function(d){return [d.data.data1]})
     .enter()
     .append('path')
     .classed("new", true)
    
  sparkPath.attr('d', line)

  sparkPath
     .attr('d', line)
     .classed("new",false)
      
  sparkPath.exit().remove()

}
update(data)
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js">
```

To clarify, the number of rows, columns, svgs, and paths remain constant between updates.

Comment: Is it fair to assume a) the number of rows may change during updates, b) there will be more than one cell per row (one of which will contain a spark line)?

Comment: @AndrewReid a) The rows will remain constant during update b) there will be multiple columns with different plots (bullets/sparklines) in the cells

Comment: During update does the number of sparklines in a row change or just the data for those sparklines?

Comment: @AndrewReid the table structure should remain constant, same parameters from different dates.  So the number of spark lines in a row should remain constant during update.

Comment: Last question, to confirm, you are running through an enter/update/exit cycle in the update function, but if I read correctly, the number of path elements is constant?

Comment: @AndrewReid please ask away!  Yes the parameters remain constant it is just the values that update.  It is a daily dashboard with the ability to go back and see previous dates.  So I build the table in the first section then constantly update when the user asks for a different date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table structure is constant (same number of rows, columns, svgs and sparklines(paths)), then we can simplify your code a bit. In your example you are updating, entering, and exiting in the update function. We don't need to do this if we aren't entering or exiting anything once the table is created.

You already add the rows, columns, svg, and path once prior to the update function, so all we need in the update function is an update selection - which let us simplify that a fair bit:

```
// Add rows once, same as before:
rows = d3.select("tbody")
  .selectAll("tr")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("tr")

// Add sparkline cell,svg, and path once, same as before:
var spark = rows.append('td')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("class", "spark-svg")
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .append('path')
  .attr("class", "spark-path")

// Only update, no need for entering/exiting if table structure doesn't change, only data:
function update(data){
  spark // use existing selection
    .data(data)  // assign new data
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return line(d.data.data1);  // draw new data
  })
}
```

This looks like:

```js
data = [{data:{data1:[{index:1, value:5},{index:4, value:9},{index:7,value:4},{index:10,value:8}]}}]

sparkScaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,10])
  .range([10,0])
sparkScaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,10])
  .range([0,15])

line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return sparkScaleX (d.index); })
  .y(function(d) { return sparkScaleY (d.value); });

// Add rows once:
rows = d3.select("tbody")
  .selectAll("tr")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("tr")

// Add title cell:
rows.append("td")
  .text(function(d) { 
    return Object.keys(d.data)[0];
  })

// Add sparkline cell,svg, and path once:
var spark = rows.append('td')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("class", "spark-svg")
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .append('path')
  .attr("class", "spark-path")

// Only update, no need for entering/exiting if table structure doesn't change, only data:
function update(data){

  spark // use the existing selection
    .data(data)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return line(d.data.data1);
  })
}
update(data)
```

```css
path {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke:black;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script><table>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And with some dynamic data

```js
var data = generate();

sparkScaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,10])
  .range([10,0])
sparkScaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,10])
  .range([0,15])

line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return sparkScaleX (d.index); })
  .y(function(d) { return sparkScaleY (d.value); });

// Add rows once:
rows = d3.select("tbody")
  .selectAll("tr")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("tr")

// Add title cell:
rows.append("td")
  .text(function(d) { 
    return d.name;
  })

// Add sparkline cell,svg, and path once:
var spark = rows.append('td')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("class", "spark-svg")
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .append('path')
  .attr("class", "spark-path")

var spark2 = rows.append('td')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("class", "spark-svg")
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .append('path')
  .attr("class", "spark-path2")
  .style("stroke","steelblue");

// Only update, no need for entering/exiting if table structure doesn't change, only data:
function update(data){

  spark
    .data(data)
    .transition()
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return line(d.spark1);
  })
  spark2
    .data(data)
    .transition()
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return line(d.spark2);
  })
  
}

update(generate());
d3.interval(function(elapsed) {
   update(generate());
}, 2000);



function generate() { 
  return d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
    return {
      name: "row"+d,
      spark1: d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
        return {index: d, value: Math.random()*10}
      }),   
      spark2: d3.range(10).map(function(d) {
        return {index: d, value: Math.random()*10}
      })       
    }
  })
}
```

```css
path {
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke:black;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script><table>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you had me at simplify.  I left work, but will check this out first thing tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: I had tried your approach before, but I always see [] around the data when doing a line plot and that is how I did a few before, but you do not have that, maybe that was my problem.  What is different about this data that it does not need the []?  Also When is it appropriate to do enter exit remove during an update?  As you say only if I am adding more rows?  I feel that most plots can get away with this pattern.

Comment: The [] in line/area graphs is to provide the enter/update cycle an array of one item: the data series (often an array of many items). The enter/update cycle creates/updates an element for each item in the data array - we want one line, not one line for each data point, so we nest the data points in a parent array. (.data also requires an array). For the exit pattern, we want to use an exit anytime the number of elements in the selection may exceed the items in the data array - in other words, when we are removing rows. There are examples where the exit is coded, but never used.